# How to fetch data that needs to be fetched only once

Tags: reactjs, angular, redux, fetch, store

I want to fetch data from an API endpoint, but I don't need to fetch it again when I come back to the screen or component again.

For example, I need a config, which determines the layout of a modal dialog, and I want to get it only when we open the dialog.
And for the next time, we open the dialog, I don't need to fetch config again.

I need solutions both for React/Redux and Angular 6+.

Comment: put a flag in module scope - it will be shared by all instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react, you could do it like this:

**Redux state**

```
{
  MODAL_CONFIG: null   // INITIAL STATE AS null
}
```

**YourModal.js**

```
// INSIDE YOUR MODAL COMPONENT

const dispatch = useDispatch();  // FROM react-redux
const MODAL_CONFIG = useSelector((state) => state.MODAL_CONFIG); // FROM react-redux

useEffect(() => {                            // EFFECT TO FETCH API
  if (MODAL_CONFIG === null) {               // WILL ONLY FETCH API IF MODAL_CONFIG STATE IS null
    fetchApiForConfig().then((data) => 
      dispatch(
        type: "UPDATE_MODAL_CONFIG",
        payload: {config: data}
      );
    );
  }
},[dispatch,MODAL_CONFIG]);

return(
  MODAL_CONFIG ?
    <YourModalUI/>    // IF MODAL_CONFIG EXISTS. DISPLAY MODAL
  : <SomeSpinner/>    // ELSE DISPLAY SPINNER
);
```

**reducer.js**

```
function reducer(state,action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_MODAL_CONFIG": {
      return({
        ...state,
        MODAL_CONFIG: action.payload.config
      });
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Lots of room for improvements, but this is basically what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

For Angular, you could cache the response using an observable in the service.

Service

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ConfigClass {
  private configSource = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);    // <-- buffer 1, will emit the last result on subscription
  public config$ = this.configSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getConfig();         // <-- call API once
  }

  getConfig() {
    this.http.get('url').subscribe(
      res => this.configSource.next(res),
      err => this.configSource.error(err)
    );
  }
}
```

Component

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  config: any;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.configService.config$.subscribe(
      res => this.config = res,
      err => { }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when SomeComponent is destroyed and recreated again?
And config service is used somewhere else?

Comment: You could include `{ providedIn: 'root' }` in the `@Injectable` decorator of the service. It'll make it singleton (only one instance). If the component is closed/destroyed and opened again, it'll get notifications from `config$` observable. The API will be triggered only once when the service is created.